# PHP ssh2_scp_send response or debugging?

Tags: php, ssh, scp, libssh2

I can't find this in any of the documentation on php.net so I'm not sure if it's a feature. Is there a response for ssh2_scp_send to check whether a file was sent successfully.

i.e. when using the line

```
ssh2_scp_send($connection, $filePath, $target);
```

Is there a call back or response that can be checked, or can it be wrapped in a try/catch to check whether the file was successful?

Comment: The documentation states that the command should have a bool return value https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.ssh2-scp-send.php but I only get null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing in the SCP protocol that does anything like that. The best you're going to be able to do is md5 or sha1 or something on the uploaded file and md5 on your original file and see if they match..

Comment: Can you explain what you mean - are you talking about creating an md5 hash of both files then comparing if they're exactly the same ?

Comment: Yup - that's it exactly!